# Return imageView rotation position and stop if at a particular position

Tags: kotlin, animation, rotation, imageview, position

hoping someone can help. I am creating an app whereby the user will touch a series of images to rotate them. What I am trying to do. Is highlight the image once the user has rotated to a particular position.

Is this possible? If, so any tips greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**edit** - ok here's an example instead!

First, the simplest way, based off the code example you just posted:

```
r1c1.setOnClickListener {
    r1c1.animate().apply{ duration = 100 rotationBy(270f) }.start()
}
```

So the issue here is that you want to highlight the view when it's rotated to, say 90 degrees, right? But it has an animation to complete first. You have three options really

- do something like `if (r1c1.rotation + 270f == 90)` and highlight now, as the animation starts, which might look weird
- do that check now, but use [`withEndAction`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator#withEndAction(java.lang.Runnable)) to run the highlighting code if necessary
- use `withEndAction` to do the checking *and* highlighting, after the anim has finished

the latter probably makes the most sense - after the animation finishes, check if its display state needs to change. That would be something like this:

```
r1c1.animate().setDuration(100).rotationBy(270f).withEndAction {
    // need to do modulo so 720 == 360 == 0 etc
    if (r1c1.rotation % 360 == TARGET_ROTATION) highlight(r1c1)
}.start()
```

I'm assuming you have some way of highlighting the `ImageView`s and you weren't asking for ways to do that!

---

Unfortunately, the problem here is that if the user taps the view in the middle of animating, it will cancel that animation and start a new one, including the `rotationBy(270)` **from whatever rotation the view currently happens to be at**. Double tap and you'll end up with a view at an angle, and it will almost never match a 90-degree value now! That's why it's easier to just hold the state, change it by fixed, valid amounts, and just tell the view what it should look like.

So instead, you'd have a value for the current rotation, update that, and use that for your highlighting checks:

```
# var stored outside the click listener - this is your source of truth
viewRotation += 270f
# using rotation instead of rotationBy - we're setting a specific value, not an offset
r1c1.animate().setDuration(100).rotation(viewRotation).withEndAction {
    // checking our internal rotation state, not the view!
    if (viewRotation % 360 == TARGET_ROTATION) highlight(r1c1)
}.start()
```

I'm not saying have a single rotation var hanging around like that - you could, but see the next bit - it's gonna get messy real quick if you have a lot of `ImageView`s to wrangle. But this is just to demonstrate the basic idea - you hold your own state value, you're in control of what it can be set to, and the `View` just reflects that state, not the other way around.

---

Ok, so organisation - I'm guessing from `r1c1` that you have a grid of cells, all with the same general behaviour. That means a lot of repeat code, unless you try and generalise it and stick it in one place - like one click listener, that does the same thing, just on whichever view it was clicked on

(I know you said youre a beginner, and I don't like loading too many concepts on someone at once, but from what it sounds like you're doing this could get incredibly bloated and hard to work with real fast, so this is important!)

Basically, [`View.onClickListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener)'s `onClick` function passes in the view that was clicked, as a parameter - basically so you can do what I've been saying, reuse the same click listener and just do different things depending on what was passed in. Instead of a lambda (the code in `{ }`, basically a quick and dirty function you're using in one place) you could make a general click listener function that you set on all your `ImageView`s

```
fun spin(view: View) {
    // we need to store and look up a rotation for each view, like in a Map
    rotations[view] = rotations[view] + 270f
    // no explicit references like r1c1 now, it's "whatever view was passed in"
    view.animate().setDuration(100).rotation(rotations[view]).withEndAction {
        // Probably need a different target rotation for each view too?
        if (rotations[view] % 360 == targetRotations[view]) highlight(view)
    }.start()
}
```

then your click listener setup would be like

```
r1c1.setOnClickListener { spin(it) }
```

or you can pass it as a function reference (this is already too long to explain, but this works in this situation, so you can use it if you want)

```
r1c1.setOnClickListener(::spin)
```

I'd recommend generating a list of all your `ImageView` cells when you look them up (there are a few ways to handle this kind of thing) but having a collection lets you do things like

```
allCells.forEach { it.setOnClickListener(::spin) }
```

and now that's all your click listeners set to the same function, and that function will handle whichever view was clicked and the state associated with it. Get the idea?

---

So your basic structure is something like

```
// maybe not vals depending on how you initialise things!
val rotations: MutableMap<View, Float>
val targetRotations: Map<View, Float>
val allCells: List<ImageView>

// or onCreateView or whatever
fun onCreate() {
    ...
    allCells.forEach { it.setOnClickListener(::spin) }
}

fun spin(view: View) {
    rotations[view] = rotations[view] + 270f
    view.animate().setDuration(100).rotation(rotations[view]).withEndAction {
        val highlightActive = rotations[view] % 360 == targetRotations[view] 
        highlight(view, highlightActive)
    }.start()
}

fun highlight(view: View, enable: Boolean) {
    // do highlighting on view if enable is true, otherwise turn it off
}
```

I didn't get into the whole "wrapper class for an `ImageView` holding all its state" thing, which would probably be a better way to go, but I didn't want to go too far and complicate things. This is already a silly length. I might do a quick answer on it just as a demonstration or whatever

Comment: Many thanks for this @cactustictacs. I will have a look into it and feedback if I can get it to work

Comment: Struggling a little with this (Must add I am a complete beginner). Would you be able to give me an example of code that I could use? one of my imageview Id's is r1c1  and I use the following code to animate to a position based on user click 
  r1c1.setOnClickListener {
        r1c1.animate().apply{
            duration =  100
            rotationBy(270f)
        }.start()
        }

Comment: I redid the answer since you have an example of what you're up to now - it's not exactly what I was talking about, but hopefully it helps you understand what's going on!

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is long enough as it is, but here's what I meant about encapsulating things

```
class RotatableImageView(val view: ImageView, startRotation: Rotation, val targetRotation: Rotation)  {

    private var rotation = startRotation.degrees

    init {
        view.rotation = rotation
        view.setOnClickListener { spin() }
        updateHighlight()
    }

    private fun spin() {
        rotation += ROTATION_AMOUNT
        view.animate().setDuration(100).rotation(rotation)
            .withEndAction(::updateHighlight).start()
    }

    private fun updateHighlight() {
        val highlightEnabled = (rotation % 360f) == targetRotation.degrees
        // TODO: highlighting!
    }

    companion object {
        const val ROTATION_AMOUNT = 90f
    }
}

enum class Rotation(var degrees: Float) {
    ROT_0(0f), ROT_90(90f), ROT_180(180f), ROT_270(270f);

    companion object {
        // just avoids creating a new array each time we call random()
        private val rotations = values()
        fun random() = rotations.random()
    }
}
```

Basically instead of having a map of `View`s to current rotation values, a map of `View`s to target values etc, all that state for each `View` is just bundled up into an object instead. Everything's handled internally, all you need to do from the outside is find your `ImageView`s in the layout, and pass them into the `RotatableImageView` constructor. That sets up a click listener and handles highlighting its `ImageView` if necessary, you don't need to do anything else!

The `enum` is just an example of creating a type to represent valid values - when you create a `RotatableImageView`, you have to pass one of these in, and the only possible values are valid rotation amounts. You could give them default values too (which could be `Rotation.random()` if you wanted) so the constructor call can just be `RotatableImageView(imageView)`

(you could make more use of this kind of thing, like using it for the internal rotation amounts too, but in this case it's awkward because 0 is not the same as 360 when animating the view, and it might spin the wrong way - so you pretty much have to keep track of the actual rotation value you're setting on the view)

---

Just as a quick FYI (and this is why I was saying what you're doing could get unwieldy enough that it's worth learning some tricks), instead of doing `findViewById` on a ton of IDs, it can be easier to just find all the `ImageView`s - wrapping them in a layout with an ID (like maybe a `GridLayout`?) can make it easier to find the things you want

```
val cells = findViewById<ViewGroup>(R.id.grid).children.filterIsInstance<ImageView>()
```

then you can do things like

```
rotatables = cells.map { RotatableImageView(it) }
```

depends what you need to do, but that's one possible way. Basically if you find yourself repeating the same thing with minor changes, like the infomercials say, There Has To Be A Better Way!

Comment: wow, thank you so much. I'm so grateful of your time to offer this help. I will have a look over the next couple of days and let you know how I get on. Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you again for your time! I have managed to get it partially working thank you, using your simplest (first) example. However, what I would like to do is, when the user has rotated all of the image views to the 'correct' position a Toast message or highlight occurs. What I have done so far, based on what you have helped me with is enabling a Toast message when each imageView is rotated to the correct position. I tried to do the if statement outstide of the on click but that did not work as I have a animated rotation before any clicks and that picks up the rotation result.

Comment: If that makes any sense whatsoever!! haha

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how you're doing your check, but I'd do this kind of process: 1) click listener starts the rotation, 2) when that finishes (e.g. using ``withEndAction`` call some function that handles un/highighting for that ``ImageView``, 3) call some function that checks the overall state for a win condition (looks at all the rotations and pops up a toast). The latter's easiest when you have a collection of all your ``ImageView``s, because you can just loop over your collection to check the win state for each item

Comment: The ``all`` keyword (https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/all.html) is useful for that last part - like with the lookup table example, you can just do ``fun playerHasWon() = allCells.all { rotation[it] = targetRotation[it] }``. Being able to generalise like that (instead of having to hardcode interactions with every individual view in the grid) makes your life a lot easier. I can't really go into detail in comments (and you should probably post other questions about specifics!) but hopefully that gives you the general idea

Comment: Thanks again for this, however I went down a slightly (easier for me) different route and just created a hidden textView and for each correctly rotated image it will add a string to the textview. when that string is complete then I added my 'highlight' code.

Comment: I mean it sounds like you're learning a bunch of stuff at once anyway, and finding stuff that works and why is part of the process! So if you have a solution that works for you, great! If you do end up needing to change it in future, you'll at least understand why you need something different - it's all part of the process eh

Comment: Thanks again for your help!!